# Android Eclipse ADT Release building project does not remove debug fields

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

Currently I am trying to build a release apk file using Eclipse ADT Export tool with private keystore using Proguard build. But it never removes debugging from the project. 
Considering the fact that, Android has updated of not adding android:debuggable="false" because of new techniques been implemented in Android. It still never removes debugging code from the project inspite of exporting the project using signed keystore and proguard enabled.
I am currently on r22 for Android SDK. 
Does anyone have any insights on why would this be an issue ? Does proguard enabled means its for release apk file or the keystore ?

Code:

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
     startActivity(new Intent().setClass(this, Testing.class));
                } else {
      startActivity(new Intent().setClass(this, TestingB.class));
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it never removes debugging code"?

Comment: Provide a sample of your "debugging code"

Comment: I tried building the app using android:debuggable="false" and also by removing it, both the times it still keeps the debugging on.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=27940) of Android platform. What we did in our project is to add a public static boolean constant named Constants.DEBUG, and use it instead of BuildConfig.DEBUG.

Comment: How would you remove Log(s) then ?

Comment: btw the #58 issue works in which we need to disable Build Automatically and try to Build it separately with separate clean of libraries if any.

Comment: what we did is we wrapped the log.e() with MyLog.e() and MyLog checks if the constant is set or not.